# GCM server java implementation nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

this is my server code snippet

```
        Result result=null;
        Sender sender = new Sender(SENDER_ID);
        Message messages = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, message).build();
        System.out.println("regId: " + to);
        try {
            result = sender.send(messages, to, 5);
            String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
            System.out.println("Broadcast failure: " + error);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

LogCat :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:166)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
at com.punchit.controllers.SendTextNotification.send(SendTextNotification.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

all the variables are correctly assigned and no variable is null
looked at many sites , but found no solution . even tried changing jar files 
any suggestion would be very helpful
Thanks

Comment: What's the line 74 in `SendTextNotification.java` ?

Answer (score 1):

You get the exception on this line (Sender.java, line 166) :

`addParameter(body, key, URLEncoder.encode(value, UTF8));`

Therefore I assume your `message` variable below is null (because that's the only value you are passing) :

```
Message messages = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
        .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, message).build();
```